# How to run Python from Windows cmd

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I am trying to run a python program in Windows with a call like this:

```
python pacman.py
```

I have many such calls to the python program. I want to run it from windows command line. When I run this in Ubuntu it works well but when I try it in Windows, I get the following error:

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How can I run these python programs from Windows cmd?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-run-a-python-program-under-windows

Comment: Python does not come pre-installed on Windows like it does with Ubuntu, so make sure you have actually [installed python](http://www.python.org/getit/) first.

Comment: Python has been installed, I can press Run from IDLE and it runs.

Answer (score 8):

You need to modify the Windows %PATH% environment variable. Under My Computer ‣ Properties ‣ Advanced ‣ Environment Variables, you should modify the %PATH% variable to include your Python directory, i.e. C:\Python26.

See: http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

That means Python Path isn't declared. Try this:

```
cd --> to pacman.py dir
C:\PythonVersion\python.exe pacman.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this, dir C:\py*, this should give you a message like this 
"Volume in Drive C:  Windows version---
Volume Serial number
Directory of C:
and a Path to Python, where it is installed on your computer", if you get this you are good to go...

Answer (score 0):

Simply calling `pacman.py` from the command line is enough if your windows is set to open `.py` files with `python.exe`. Which is easily done through the file manager. (And gets set by default when installing python.)